# getCurrentPosition doesn't work on ionic application

Tags: angular, google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I am working on ionic application.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { RoleService } from '../../services/role.service';
import { RoleViewDto } from '../../contracts/role/roleViewDto';
import { RoleType } from '../../contracts/enums/enums';

import { GoogleMapsService } from '../../services/google-maps.service';
import { CommonService } from '../../services/common.service';

declare var google;

@Component({
    selector: 'pwssr-welcome',
    templateUrl: 'welcome.page.html',
})
export class WelcomePage implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
map: any;
role: RoleViewDto;
roleType = RoleType;

lat: number;
lng: number;

marker: any;

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public geolocation: Geolocation,
    private roleService: RoleService,
    private googleMapsService: GoogleMapsService,
    private commonService: CommonService,
) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.commonService.setTitle("Sweet Rides");
    this.roleService.getRole().subscribe((res) => {
        this.role = res;
    });
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
}

loadMap() {

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

        let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-32.3003176, 115.7749078);

        this.map = this.googleMapsService.get(latLng, this.mapElement);

    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('[DEBUG] Promise Unfulfilled. ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });


}
```

this code is working on web browsers but it doesn't work on android devices after building apk. I installed the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins using this tutorial https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/

```
ionic info

cli packages: (C:\Users\Peda\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

   @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
   ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0

System:

    Node : v6.11.2
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Looks like this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition doesn't work. Also I don't have any error messages in console

Comment: im curious, does it ask you if it can use your location on android?

Comment: Yes it asks me. But after that nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know:

```
 let element = document.getElementById('map');
 let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);       
 map.getMyLocation((loc: any)=>{
        console.log("--Latitude--" + loc.latLng.lat);
        console.log("--Longitude--" + loc.latLng.lng);
       }).catch((error) => {
          console.log("--Error--");
        });
```